# Table and form submit

Tags: php, mysql, forms

[image]

I have to submit all values in different cell in database with one submit
When I click submit it only inserts last student and last subject marks
example (flinch and physics):

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    $query="SELECT *FROM `students` WHERE `standard`='".$standard."'";
    $ex_query=mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ex_query)) {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $fname=$row['fname'];
        $lname=$row['lname'];
        $rollno = $row['rollno'];
        $standard = $row['standard'];
        $section = $row['section'];
    ?>

                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td><?php echo $fname; ?> <?php echo $lname; ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $fname; ?> <?php echo $lname; ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $standard; ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="standard" value="<?php echo $standard; ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $section; ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="section" value="<?php echo $section; ?>">
                    </td>
                    <?php  $querysub="SELECT *FROM `subject`";
                            $ex_querysub=mysql_query($querysub);
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ex_querysub))
                                {
                    $id=$row['id'];
                    $subject=$row['subject'];
                 ?>

                    <td><input type="hidden" name="subject" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>"><input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="marks"></td>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <!-- <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="edit(<?php echo $id ?>)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="deldata(<?php echo $id ?>)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td> -->
                </tr>
            <?php } 
        ?>                              
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit">


<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $id 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $standard = $_POST['standard'];
    $section = $_POST['section'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $marks = $_POST['marks'];

    $query="INSERT INTO `marks` (`id` ,`name` ,`standard` ,`section`  ,`subject` ,`marks`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$standard', '$section', '$subject', '$marks')";
    $ex_query=mysql_query($query); ?>
    <!-- <script>
        window.location.href="view-standard.php";
    </script> -->   <?php
}
}
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Each row contains form elements with the same name. The last elements are overriding the previous ones. Changing the element name in each row (adding a row index) should help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a row index to each elements name like this

```
<tr>
  <th scope="row">1
  </th>
  <td>
    <?php echo $fname; ?> 
    <?php echo $lname; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $fname; ?> <?php echo $lname; ?>">
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $standard; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="standard[]" value="<?php echo $standard; ?>">
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $section; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="section[]" value="<?php echo $section; ?>">
  </td>
  <?php  $querysub="SELECT *FROM `subject`";
$ex_querysub=mysql_query($querysub);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ex_querysub))
{
$id=$row['id'];
$subject=$row['subject'];
?>
  <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="subject[]" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>">
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="marks">
  </td>
  <?php } ?>
  <!-- <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="edit(<?php echo $id ?>)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="deldata(<?php echo $id ?>)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td> -->
</tr>
```

Then when you access `$_POST['name']` for example you will get an array with all values and you can use a loop and insert them in database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ex_querysub)) {
    ?>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="form[<?php echo $i; ?>]['name']" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="form[<?php echo $i; ?>]['section']" value="<?php echo $row['section']; ?>" />
    </td>
    .... you got the idea
    <?php

    $i++;
}
```

> Always use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`.

And the action itself

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['form'])) {
     foreach ($_POST['form'] as $row) {
          $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO marks SET 
          name = '%s',
          section = '%s'
          ... add all fields here
           ", 
          strip_tags($row['name']), // you should always sanitize your input from user. Or you'll have SQL Injection problems
          strip_tags($row['section']),
          );

          mysql_query($sql);
     }
}
```

> I alwasy prefer to use the second form of INSERT statement http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html . It's similar to UPDATE and it's easier to understand. specially if you have big insert queries. Usually primary key which is auto_increment should be skipped on inserts